# If statement seems to skip though requirements are met

Tags: java, string, if-statement, equals

I have a very simple question that I really can't understand.

I have a method that takes a string and determines what the first character of the string is, and then returns it.

```
public String deterFirstChar(String value){
    String keyValue;
    char res; 
    res = value.charAt(0);
    keyValue = Character.toString(res);
    if (keyValue == "C"){
        return keyValue;
    } else if (keyValue == "G") {
        return keyValue;
    }
    System.out.println("Error: Wrong keyParam");
    return "F";
}
```

However, intstead of returning, for an example keyValue = C, it skipps the if statement and returns "F" when I know for sure that keyValue is "C".

Why is this occurring?

Comment: Requirements are not met at all. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Strings use .equals() and not the == operator.

Comment: To compare two strings, you should use the equals method: if (keyValue.equals("C")) {

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, check [How do i compare string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Secondly, you don't have to convert the char to String to check its value, you can do it like below

```
res = value.charAt(0);
//keyValue = Character.toString(res); NOT REQUIRED
if (res == 'C'){
    return Character.toString(res);
} else if (res == 'G') {
```

Comment: The method returns a String, so you'd either need to convert the char to string before returning or change the return type, too.

Comment: @sanbhat, upvote for the idea of converting character to String

Comment: Thanks for the answers, this works very well! I tried this at first, but I used "C" instead of 'C'. Is "" exclusive for strings?

Comment: Yes, `""` represents String and `''` represents character

Answer (score 4):

You should not compare strings using `==`, use `equals()` method

```
 if (someString.equals("C")){
        return someString;
    } else if (someString.equals("G")) {
        return someString;
    }
```

- `==` checks whether two variables refer to the same object.
- `equals()` method checks whether the contents of the object are same or not.
- so If `==` returns true, then `equals()` method also returns true because they are referring to the same object hence they are equal

You can find a great explanation for [string comparison with equals and assignment](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/27/string-comparison-with-equals-and-assignment-operator/)
If you want to use characters,

```
res = value.charAt(0);
if (res == 'C'){
    return Character.toString(res);
} else if (res == 'G') {
    return Character.toString(res);
 }
```

Comment: May I please know the reason for downvote? so that I can correct myself?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this, now it works like a charm!
However, it would work when comparing a, for example int like: 
if(int i = 1) {do stuff}?

Comment: This is because int is a primitive and comparison is different for object types and primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static char findFirstChar(String string){
    return string.charAt(0);
}
    char out = findFirstChar("Rakesh");
    System.out.println("First Character:"+out);
```